# JS check if input is in array range

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to validate input using JavaScript, what i want is to bring up an alert if the user enters something that is not included in my array.

Here is what i have so far

```
var validAr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","m","M"];
//dont mind the i it's been previously declared
val =+ document.getElementById('arrow_' + i + '_1').value

alert(val);
alert(validAr.indexOf(val));
```

If for example in the above the user enters '5' I'll alert '5', the value of `val` and then -1 which means that it does not belong to the array. How do I solve this?

Comment: I think you better use regular expression for such kind of validations. here is a useful reference http://tech.pro/tutorial/1214/javascript-regular-expression-enlightenment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array contains strings but you're converting the value to a number:

```
val = +document.getElementById('arrow_'+i+'_1').value
//    ^ Remove this to keep the value as a string
```

Since `Array.prototype.indexOf` performs a strict equality comparison it fails to find the value in the array.

You *could* replace the values of your array with actual numbers, but since `"m"` and `"M"` will not convert to numbers it won't work that way (you'll end up with `NaN` when you try to coerce them).

Comment: Yes now i understand, im converting it to number cause i need it later. Converted to string just for the validation and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

just convert your value in string

```
    alert(validAr.indexOf(val.toString()));
```

and also remove + from +document.getElementById('arrow_'+i+'_1').value

so your code will be

```
var validAr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","m","M"];
//dont mind the i it's from a for above
val = document.getElementById('arrow_'+i+'_1').value;

alert(val);
alert(validAr.indexOf(val.toString()));
```

Comment: Yes, i was using the + cause i need the number of it later. That fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        var validAr = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "m", "M"];

        $("#text").change(function () {
            if (jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), validAr) == -1) {
                alert("exception");
            }
        });
    });

<input type="text" id="text" />
```

Comment: why not just go with < 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery you can do:

```
if (jQuery.inArray(val,validAr)==-1)
{
    alert('Invalid');
}
```